# Windows Forms, dataGridView не отображает данные из DataTable

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview, dataset

Следующий код принимает данные из файла data.txt по нажатию на кнопку. Заполняет DataTable table столбцами, зачем строками. Далее я добавляю в dataGridView1 столбцы из table, указывая при этом DataPropertyName, но программа не работает корректно. Прошу помощи.
Файл хранит себе данные для построения графика:
Файл обязательно должен содержать столбец с аргументом x. Столбцов, как и строк, может быть неограниченное количество.
Для построения графика в качестве координат используется аргумент и выбранный пользователем столбец данных (y или z в данном случае).

```
x,y,z
0,0,1
1,5,5
2,3,2
```

```
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("data.txt");
            string fileText = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
            string[] strs = fileText.Split(new char[] {'\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            ds.Tables.Add();
            string[] columns = strs[0].Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
            {
                DataColumn a = new DataColumn(columns[i].ToString());
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(a);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < strs.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] date = strs[i].Split(',');
                DataRow rw = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                rw.ItemArray = date;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rw);
            }
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn a = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                a.HeaderText = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName;
                a.DataPropertyName = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(a);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Comment: Какие данные хранятся в текстовом файле? Какие-то сериализованные объекты в формате json? Отредактируйте вопрос и укажите пример для более точного ответа на ваш вопрос

Comment: А дальше? В следующих ниже строках стоят 3 числа (координаты) и всё или что-то ещё скрывается за этими ". . . "?

Comment: Файл обязательно должен содержать столбец с аргументом x. Столбцов, как и строк, может быть неограниченное количество.

Comment: Уточните: столбцов действительно может быть сколько угодно и заранее их количество неизвестно? Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При чтении строк используйте ReadAllLines. Данный метод возвращает string[], который вы сможете вставить в метод Create.

Решение, которое я предлагаю ниже - сделать привязку напрямую класса с данными к dgv, а не заполнять в лоб datatable (? зачем-то...) и потом уже её привязывать к данным

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var line = new List<string>()
    {
        "x,y,z",
        "2,3,1",
        "5,1,3"
    }; //тестовые данные. У вас тоже самое, но в массиве храниться будет
    var bindingList = Create(line); //для конвертации из массива в лист используйте `.ToList()`
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingList; //сама привязка
}
```

Метод, который создаёт BindingSource

```
private BindingSource Create(IEnumerable<string> fileList)
{
    var columnsName = fileList.First().Split(','); //не используется, но вдруг будет нужно
    //Названия колонок берутся из класса XYZ из свойств

    var rows = new BindingList<XYZ>();
    foreach (var row in fileList.Skip(1))
    {
        var values = row.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        rows.Add(new XYZ(values[0], values[1], values[2]));
    }
    return new BindingSource(rows, default);
}
```

Класс XYZ

```
internal class XYZ
{
    public int X { get; private set; }

    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public int Z { get; private set; }

    public XYZ(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

Вставленные в таблицу данные выглядят следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение. Как мне кажется, я нашёл ошибку в своём решении, но не понимаю чем она вызвана.
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rw);
Не заполняет table строками, list строк оказывается пустым по итогам цикла.

Comment: Ваша решение само по себе странное. Зачем заполнять сначала какую-то таблицу, а затем эту таблицу вставлять в другую таблицу? Почему нельзя сделать мега-просто, как показал я выше, через привязку данных. Это удобнее и вы сможете изменять данные во время работы программы, не обновляя таблицу. Так же, извлекать данные будет гораздо проще (не нужно обращаться к ячейке. Нужно напрямую в объекту, который привязан) и тд и тп

Comment: Но ведь автор пишет, что столбцов может быть неограниченное количество. Следовательно класс с фиксированным количеством свойств не подойдёт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не обратил внимание на то, что количество столбцов неограниченное количество. Если это действительно так (хотя, не помню, чтоб координат использовалось больше чем 3), то тут 2 пути - сделать, как изначально делал автор - тупо заполнить таблицу через цикл, но убрав лишнюю dataTable ИЛИ чуть запариться и создавать класс в рантайме с помощью рефлексии

Comment: Нашёл даже готовое решение, касаемо создания классов - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class

Comment: Прошу прощения за ваше время, но я всё равно воспользуюсь знанием, которые вы предложили. Ошибка оказалась типичной, и тем ещё ужасней - я создал несколько экземпляров класса DataDridVIew при  заполнении формы и всё время обращался не к тому экземпляру......

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Если у вас много однотипных классов, то может стоит задуматься над созданием базового класса, от которого остальные будут наследоваться? Если вы понятия не имеете, какие данные будете выводить, то используйте всё-таки методы, которые я предложил выше (заполнение таблицы в лоб или создание классов в runtime и привязка их к dgv). Если вам требуется помощь, не стесняйтесь создавать вопросы с тегом `инспекция-кода`, но тщательно следите за оформлением таких вопросов